# How to monitor and log processor, memory and other details for website running behind IIS?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis, performance, monitoring

I have ASP.NET application installed behind IIS 6.0(Windows Server 2K3). Now when i run the application and i would like to get some load testing scenarios to work on this. While doing the load test i would like to monitor/log the detains like processor, memory and other details related with the w3p process with specific port on which the web application is running.

I would like to get a better results say having graph showing ups and downs of memory consumption. Also i would like to perform this operation per use case/workflow basis to identify potential issues early.

I am aware about only "Performance Logs and Alerts" that is in the "Computer Management" section. However i am having really hard timing using it considering the number of system variable and stuff with it. I feel it really hard to read and use.

Is there any better option to do this task? So that this task can be done easily with more clarity and control ?

Comment: I think that Perfmon is probably the best tool in my experience for this job. You can have it log the data to say a `csv` file and the process the data in your tool of choice. If you get stuck on particular parts of trying to use it you can always ask those specific questions on this site -- lots of people have experience with it.

Comment: Thanks for reply Kyle. I will then get started with this same tool.

Comment: +1 to Kyle's comment.  Once you learn a few favorite counters, perfmon is straight forward and very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to look at PAL: http://pal.codeplex.com/

It has built-in templates to use for performance monitor depending on what apps you want to monitor (IIS, Exchange, SQL, etc.) and when you're done it'll generate an awesome report for you based on thresholds you can set.

We use it to test all of our apps and it's invaluable when we need to figure out which of many apps are causing server troubles.